# PyEphem: coordinate transformation galactic to equatorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyephem

I have an issue with PyEphem when trying to make a coordinate transformation. Basically in this little example I try to calculate the equatorial coordinates of (l,b) = (52°,68.5°).

This is how I thought it should work:

```
import ephem

galactic = ephem.Galactic(52.0/360.0,68.5/360.0)
equatorial = ephem.Equatorial(galactic, epoch=ephem.J2000)
print('%.13f %.13f' % (equatorial.ra*360.0, equatorial.dec*360.0))
```

The output is `1640.9226879684597 -101.5405093325453` which is of course not what I expect given that ranges are 0° to 360° for RA and -90° to 90° for DEC.

Where is the error?

**EDIT**

I need to transform degree to radians as pointed out by the correct answer. My solution at the end:

```
import ephem
import math

galactic = ephem.Galactic(52.0/180.0*math.pi,68.5/180.0*math.pi)
equatorial = ephem.Equatorial(galactic, epoch=ephem.J2000)
print('%.13f %.13f' % (equatorial.ra/math.pi*180.0, equatorial.dec/math.pi*180.0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equatorial.ra` and `equatorial.dec` are in radians.

```
>>> help(equatorial.ra)
Help on Angle object:

class Angle(builtins.float)
 |  An angle in radians that can print itself in an astronomical format.
 |  Use ephem.degrees() and ephem.radians() to create one.
 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I have no experience with the ephem module I am pretty sure it expects strings as arguments to `Galactic()` and `Equatorial()`. Consequentally, they return a tuple of strings then, not float.